# Adding multiple users jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanne add multiple users in jQuery. I have the following code but it doesnt work. Does someone knows why?

Thanks!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#add').click(function(){
        var newuser = $.html('Gebruiker: <input type="text" name="user[]"><br />');

        $(newuser).appendTo('#users');
    });
});


</script>
<section>
<span id="add">Nieuwe gebruiker</span><br /><br /><br />
<form action="" method="" id="users">

<input type="submit" name="send" value="verzenden">
</form>
```

Comment: The new input field wont show up. I tried different codes but none of them work. With my current code i receive: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new b.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'html'  I know that $.html() doesnt work, but none of my tries helped

Comment: is there something `$.html()`??

Answer (score 1):

Use simply string in your variable, no jQuery `.html()` function required. Then change your `.appendTo()` function to `.append()` and define the element in jQuery selector.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#add').click(function(){
        var newuser = 'Gebruiker: <input type="text" name="user[]"><br />';
        $('#users').append(newuser);
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesnt work. Getting this error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Gebruiker: <input type="text" name="user[]"><br />

Comment: @DonnyvanV please provide a fiddle

Comment: Now i want to remove the element. My new code is  this: http://jsfiddle.net/x52Cf/1/    It doesnt even get clicked because no log will show up

Comment: You're running into dynamically created elements problems. For those, you need to use `.on` rather than `.click`. JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x52Cf/2/

Comment: Use  $(document).on('click','.delete', function(){
   $(this).remove();
   console.log('reached');
  }); ... However you need to wrap all in a div to select all containing elements... I have updated my answer below...

Answer (score 1):

In case you are wondering why your current code is not working:

***string starting with anything other than "<" is not considered HTML string in jQuery 1.9***

http://stage.jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring

Therefore this code will work fine (as it starts with <):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#add').click(function(){
        $('<input type="text" name="user[]">').appendTo('#users');
    });
});
```

And for your current code to work ***use $.parseHTML***:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#add').click(function(){
        var newuser = $.parseHTML('Gebruiker: <input type="text" name="user[]"><br />');

        $(newuser).appendTo('#users');
    });
});
```

$.parseHTML is used to parse the arbitrary HTML so that it is not taken as a selector by jQuery.

***Edit: adding delete feature:***

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#add').click(function(){
        var newuser = $.parseHTML('<div><label>Gebruiker:</label> <input type="text" name="user[]"><span class="delete">Verwijderen</span></div>');
        $(newuser).appendTo('#users');
    });
    $(document).on('click','.delete', function(){ 
          $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
          console.log('reached'); 
    }); 
});
```

*jsFiddle Example:* http://jsfiddle.net/RtTpN/

Answer (score 0):

yep, there is nothing called `$.html()` in jQuery. `html` is a method of set of nodes instead.

You can do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add').click(function () {
        $('#users').append('Gebruiker: <input type="text" name="user[]"><br />');
    });
});
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/dfpYA/)